# Sleep wake failure in EFI & turning off the touch bar (Macbook Pro)

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, kernel-panic

I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports) running MacOS 11.3.1 (Big Sur), and I have been getting sleep-wake failures for a few months now (even when I was running Catalina).

Basically, every my computer goes to sleep, it crashes, and has to restart. This is very annoying, since I cannot leave my computer for long without it restarting. Even if I put it to sleep manually (and even when I shut it down and restart it!), this happens.

The error message is typically something like "panic: Sleep Wake failure in EFI." I suspect that it has to do with my touchbar, especially since I see the touchbar going crazy (the LEDs flash crazily) every time I open my computer lid.

My questions are:

1. Does anyone know how to fix this sleep-wake failure? Is it a software issue I can fix, or is it a software issue only Apple can fix, or is it a hardware issue that I can go to a repair shop for?
2. How can I fully disable my touchbar? I want to see if doing so fixes the problem.

I've seen numerous posts about this elsewhere, but nowhere has a satisfactory answer, so please don't mark this as a duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: You can start, if not already done, by doing Reset SMC and Reset NVRAM.

Comment: I have had the same issue. resetting SMC and NVRAM doesn't help long term, even though it fixes it for the short term. Seems mine panics each time I try to put it to sleep - only shutting down before closing the lid prevents the panic (but what's the point of that?)